# ¿Como puedo hacer que mi tabla se ajuste automáticamente al texto? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Quisiera que mi tabla se ajustara automáticamente sin que me de el salto de línea en el texto, quiero que si el registro poniendo como ejemplo el nombre, es muy largo que ese campo se vaya haciendo ancho, me han dicho que la haga responsiva, ya lo hice así pero no es la solución, lo hice con `Bootstrap` pero no funciona.

De igual forma les agrego el código para ver si alguien tiene la solución, ya que he estado batallando con ese pequeño detalle.

Esta es la forma en la que lo hace
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la forma en la que quisiera que quedara. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$("#dtRecetas").tableHeadFixer();
    var table = $('#dtRecetas').DataTable({

        fixedHeader: {
            header: true,
            footer: true
        },
        responsive: true,
        "scrollY": 387,
        "scrollX": true,
        scrollCollapse: false,

        language: {
            emptyTable: "<i>No hay datos disponibles en la tabla</i>",
            info: "Del _START_ al _END_ de _TOTAL_",
            infoEmpty: "Mostrando 0 registros de un total de 0",
            infoFiltered: "(filtrados de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            infoPostFix: "(actualizados)",
            lengthMenu: "Mostrar _MENU_ Registros",
            loadingRecords: "Cargando...",
            processing: "Procesando...",
            search: "<span style='font-size:15px;'>Buscar:</sapn>",
            searchPlaceholder: "Dato para buscar",
            zeroRecords: "No se han encontrado coincidencias",

            paginate: {
                first: "Primera",
                last: "Última",
                next: "Siguiente",
                previous: "Anterior"
            }
        },
        ordering: false

    });
```

Y este es mi código HTML:

```
@model IEnumerable<Vitamedica.Farmacia.Entidades.Recetas>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<br />
<img src="~/fonts/logo2.png" />
<br />
<div class="text-center">
    <h1>Surtido de Recetas</h1>
</div>
<hr />
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/VitaMedica/Recetas.js"></script>
</head>
<div>
    <div class="col-sm-10"></div>
    <button class="col-sm-2 btn btn-primary" id="Actualiza">Actualizar</button>
    @*<input type="button" value="Actualizar" onclick="location.reload()" />*@
</div>
<br />
<br />
<table class="table table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Seleccione" id="dtRecetas">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Derechohabiente)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Elegibilidad)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FolioReceta)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.TantoReceta)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Contador)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CodigoEAN)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DescripcionMedicamento)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Unidades)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Preautorizacion)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FechaConsulta)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Copago)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.TipoEmpleado)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.EstatusEmpleado)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.NumeroTelefono)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.TipoTelefono)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CantidadToma)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Periodicidad)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DuracionTratamiento)
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbodyHistorico">

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Derechohabiente)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Elegibilidad)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FolioReceta)
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TantoReceta)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contador)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CodigoEAN)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DescripcionMedicamento)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Unidades)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Preautorizacion)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FechaConsulta)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Copago)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TipoEmpleado)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EstatusEmpleado)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumeroTelefono)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TipoTelefono)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CantidadToma)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Periodicidad)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DuracionTratamiento)
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que los datos se muestren en una linea, debes cambiar los espacios de todos los textos de la tabla por espacios duros.

Para esto existen 2 opciones:

**Cambiarlos desde el servidor con C#:** para eso tienes que cambiar los espacios de todas las cadenas que se muestran en la tabla por `&nbsp;` con `Replace()`:

```
cadena.Replace(' ', '&nbsp;');
```

**Cambiarlos en la pagina con Jquery:** en esta solución se reemplazan todas los espacios de los textos dentro de las celdas por espacios duros en su forma cruda (`'\xa0'`):

Con este método el código queda funcionando de la siguiente forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  [...$('td')].map(e => e.textContent =
  e.textContent.trim().split(' ').join('\xa0'));
  [...$('th')].map(e => e.textContent =
  e.textContent.trim().split(' ').join('\xa0'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table class="table table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Seleccione" id="dtRecetas">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Derechohabiente
            </th>
            <th>
                Elegibilidad
            </th>
            <th>
                Folio Receta
            </th>
            <th>
                Tanto Receta
            </th>
            <th>
                Contador de Recetas
            </th>
            <th>
                Codigo EAN
            </th>
            <th>
                Descripcion Medicamento
            </th>
            <th>
                Unidades
            </th>
            <th>
                Preautorizacion
            </th>
            <th>
                FechaConsulta
            </th>
            <th>
                Copago
            </th>
            <th>
                Tipo Empleado
            </th>
            <th>
                Estatus Empleado
            </th>
            <th>
                Numero Telefono
            </th>
            <th>
                Tipo Telefono
            </th>
            <th>
                Cantidad Toma
            </th>
            <th>
                Periodicidad
            </th>
            <th>
                Duracion Tratamiento
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbodyHistorico">
            <tr>
                <td>
                      ERNESTINA CAMARGO MORALES
                </td>
                <td>
                    527481717
                </td>
                <td>
                    11847397239832
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    1
                </td>
                <td>
                    1/1
                </td>
                <td>
                    78490780394933034
                </td>
                <td>
                    ERIZIC 250 MG
                </td>
                <td>
                    1
                </td>

                <td>
                    -
                </td>
                <td>
                    -
                </td>
                
                <td>
                    -
                </td>
                <td>
                    -
                </td>
                <td>
                    -
                </td>
                <td>
                    -
                </td>
                <td>
                    -
                </td>
                <td>
                    -
                </td>
                <td>
                    -
                </td>
                <td>
                    -
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Esta solución es mas simple ya que solo basta con agregar el código Jquery para que funcione.

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono con Jquery, saludos agradezco mucho tu ayuda