# Tabla con muchas columnas hace saltar de linea a la columna que la que la contiene

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tengo dos columnas, una es el menú, y la otra el contenido principal, el problema es que en la columna de contenido quiero poner una tabla pero tiene muchas columnas y hace que salte al siguiente `.row`.

Ya intente agregarle la clase `.table-responsive`para añadirle el scroll en el eje x pero no funciona, sigue saltando de linea. ¿Existe alguna forma de obligar a la columna para que no salte de linea?

Mi código simplificado:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
      
      <!--Menu-->
      <div class="col-auto d-lg-block d-none" style="background: #ccc; min-width: 300px; min-height: 100vh;">
      (contenido del menu)
      </div>
        

         <div class="col" style="background: #308B92;">
            <div class="table-responsive ">
              <table class="table table-dark">
                 <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>RFC</th>
                        <th>Calle</th>
                        <th>no_ext</th>
                        <th>no_int</th>
                        <th>colonia</th>
                        <th>ciudad</th>
                        <th>id_estado_republica</th>
                        <th>cp</th>
                        <th>correo</th>
                        <th>telefono_1</th>
                        <th>telefono_2</th>
                        <th>telefono_3</th>
                        <th>web</th>
                        <th>comentarios</th>
                        <th>rfc_banco</th>
                        <th>no_cuenta</th>
                        <th>dias_credito</th>
                        <th>activo</th>
                        <th class="opciones-generales"></th>
                    </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                 
                   <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Nombre</td>
                    <td>RFC</td>
                    <td>Calle</td>
                    <td>no_ext</td>
                    <td>no_int</td>
                    <td>colonia</td>
                    <td>ciudad</td>
                    <td>id_estado_republica</td>
                    <td>cp</td>
                    <td>correo</td>
                    <td>telefono_1</td>
                    <td>telefono_2</td>
                    <td>telefono_3</td>
                    <td>web</td>
                    <td>comentarios</td>
                    <td>rfc_banco</td>
                    <td>no_cuenta</td>
                    <td>dias_credito</td>
                    <td>activo</td>
                    <td ></td>
                  </tr>
                 <tbody>
              </table>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Este es el problema, el salto de linea]

[image: Ahí le quite columnas para que se muestre la tabla como deseo, pero quiereo que se muestre el scroll horizontal para poder mostrar los demas campos]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, para evitar los saltos de linea en tu tabla talvez te sirva revisar esta respuesta en [¿Como puedo hacer que mi tabla se ajuste automáticamente al texto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/298355/77879)

Comment: Gracias amigo, pero lo que salta no es el contenido de la tabla, si no el contenedor padre de la tabla, se posiciona como si fuera el footer :(

Comment: entendido, podrías agregar el código del menú que quieres colocar en la otra columna? así te es mas fácil indicarte como lo puedes posicionar.

Comment: aunque con bootstrap bastaría con agregarles a ambas columnas la clase `class="col-6"` por ejemplo,

Comment: cierto, olvide esa columna, el menu es de 300px con la clase `.col-auto` y el contenido es donde va la tabla es `.col`  para que ocupe lo que resta del 
 `container-fluid`

Comment: veo que estas aplicando muchos estilos y clases, imagino que es para hacer la vista responsiva, eso lo hace mas complicado, tal vez deberías explicar el comportamiento que esperas.

Comment: en si los estilos responsivos funcionan bien y lo unico que hacen es ocultar la barra lateral izquierda cuando el tamaño del viewport es menor a un tamaño largo, si le quito los estilos `d-lg-block` y `d-block` la barra de menu quedara siempre fija y en teoria la tabla que va dentro del contenido se deberia mostrar al lado derecho pero se salta la linea como si ocurriera un overflow

Comment: entiendo, ya intentaste colocando la clase `col-6` a ambas columnas? parece que eso puede resolver el problema.

Comment: ya probe con eso pero hace saltos segun la cantidad de columnas que agrego de la tabla, y solo quiero que el menu mida 300px, añadi unas imagenes para ver mostrar mejor el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que el menú siempre tenga un ancho de `300px` y el `div` que contiene en la tabla se acomode en el resto del espacio lo puedes hacer agregando la regla:

```
width:calc(100% - 300px);
```

a dicho div:

*(Para observar el resultado has clic en el botón de pantalla completa)*

```css
#menu{
  background: #ccc; 
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#tabla{
  background: #308B92;
  width:calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
      
      <!--Menu-->
      <div id="menu" class="col d-lg-block d-none" >
      (contenido del menu)
      </div>
        
         <div id="tabla" class="col" >
            <div class="table-responsive ">
              <table class="table table-dark">
                 <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>RFC</th>
                        <th>Calle</th>
                        <th>no_ext</th>
                        <th>no_int</th>
                        <th>colonia</th>
                        <th>ciudad</th>
                        <th>id_estado_republica</th>
                        <th>cp</th>
                        <th>correo</th>
                        <th>telefono_1</th>
                        <th>telefono_2</th>
                        <th>telefono_3</th>
                        <th>web</th>
                        <th>comentarios</th>
                        <th>rfc_banco</th>
                        <th>no_cuenta</th>
                        <th>dias_credito</th>
                        <th>activo</th>
                        <th class="opciones-generales"></th>
                    </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                 
                   <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Nombre</td>
                    <td>RFC</td>
                    <td>Calle</td>
                    <td>no_ext</td>
                    <td>no_int</td>
                    <td>colonia</td>
                    <td>ciudad</td>
                    <td>id_estado_republica</td>
                    <td>cp</td>
                    <td>correo</td>
                    <td>telefono_1</td>
                    <td>telefono_2</td>
                    <td>telefono_3</td>
                    <td>web</td>
                    <td>comentarios</td>
                    <td>rfc_banco</td>
                    <td>no_cuenta</td>
                    <td>dias_credito</td>
                    <td>activo</td>
                    <td ></td>
                  </tr>
                 <tbody>
              </table>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Luego te recomiendo tener una clase `css` para el menú y el `div` de la tabla en lugar de cambiarle las propiedades directamente con `style`.

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: Casi funciona, pero el menu es muy ancho, requiero que sea de 300px como maximo, cambie los anchos de columna a `.col-lg-3` y `.col-lg-9` pero sigue haciendo el salto :(

Comment: @asaelj ya tengo resuelto para que el menú siempre tenga un ancho de 300 y el otro div se acomode al espacio restante.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que necesito, ahora si permanece en su lugar la columna 
Gracias :)

Comment: @asaelj de nada, para eso estamos.

Answer (score 1):

he comprobado tu código y a mí no me aparece ningún salto de línea. Comprueba si has añadido todos los scripts para que funcione bootstrap.

```html
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  
  <body>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, ya intente con los mdn propuestos pero sigue haciendo el salto de `row`, se posiciona como si fuera el footer, cuando deberia esta al lado derecho de la columna menu

Comment: Es que el problema no se notaba por que olvide agregar la columna del menú, se salta al siguiente `row`